# Triangle Problem with Triangle Congruency

Tags: geometry, triangles

I came across this question and I could not solve it. It is probably really easy and I'm missing the point, but could someone please help?

[image: Triangle]

Comment: There are two specific triangles in there that can be proven to be congruent. Once you do that you're basically done. Recall SAS

Comment: I see triangle BAO and triangle DCO but none others

Comment: What does this have to do with modular *arithmetic*?

Comment: @GeometryPonderer Good so far, can you prove that these two triangles are congruent? Do you know the SAS congruence theorem?

Comment: @Allawonder I edited the tag and changed it to be more appropriate

Comment: @WaveX yes BOA and DOC are vertical, and the sides are congruent, therefore the triangle is congruent by SAS

Comment: @GeometryPonderer Yup! You're at the home stretch now. $\angle ACD$ can now be broken up into two **known** angles.

Comment: @WaveX But we only know measure of angle 2, and no other angle can be shown equal to OCD by CPCTC. What are you sugggesting.

Comment: @WaveX I got it!

Answer (score 0):

$\text{Consider}$ $□ ABCD,$

$\text{It is given that}$ $AO=OD,OB=OC\implies$ $\text{Diagonals are bisected}$ $\implies □ ABCD$ $\text{is a parallelogram.}$

$\implies ∠ABC=∠BCD$

$ \implies ∠ACD=∠ACB+∠ABC \implies ∠ACD = 74+36$
$=\boxed{110}$